# How can I update the variable of another file?

Tags: python, schedule

Let's say I have two files, one (test.py):

```
import time
import schedule

variables = [1, 2, 3]

def augment():
    for i in range(3):
        variables[i] += (i+1)

schedule.every().second.do(augment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

And then another file (test2.py):

```
import test
import time
import schedule

def take_a_look():
    print(test.variables)

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(take_a_look)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I guess multithreading could work too, but still, my plan was to execute test.py and then test2.py, but I guess test.py would run twice then (once on its own and then once inside test2.py's proccess?). Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute both processes separately, they're each going to have their own memory spaces. Changes in one is not going to directly affect the other.

If you want two separate running processes to communicate, you need to use some form of shared memory. There's a [library for pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html) that might be useful, but without other context, I don't know if that's what will work best for you.